# How to add Dynamic Entities in Alexa with Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a Alexa Skill in Python and I need to dynamically add Entities for the user to update a Slot Type so the user can choose an option.

I the page [Use Dynamic Entities for Customized Interactions](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/use-dynamic-entities-for-customized-interactions.html) there is documentation and example for Node.js and Java, but no examples for Python. Looking at the [Documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/alexa-skills-kit-python-sdk/downloads/pdf/latest/) for the Python SDK, it was not clear to me how to do the same in Python.

I created a Slot Type called **test** and tried the following code:

```
test_directive = {"object_type": "Dialog.UpdateDynamicEntities", "update_behavior": "REPLACE", "types": [{"name": "test", "values": [{"id": "round-rock", "name": {"value": "Round Rock Express", "synonyms": ["Round Rock", "Express"]}}, {"id": "corpus-christi", "name": {"value": "Corpus Christi Hooks", "synonyms": ["Corpus Christi", "Hooks", "Corpus"]}}]}]}

response_builder.add_directive(test_directive)
```

But I get the error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'object_type'
```

What is the correct way to add dynamic entities in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the link: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/210684/dynamic-entities-in-python.html. A short example in Python:

```
entity_synonyms_1 = EntityValueAndSynonyms(value="entity 1", synonyms=["synonym 1", "synonym 2"])
entity_1 = Entity(id="entity_id_1", name=entity_synonyms_1)

entity_synonyms_2 = EntityValueAndSynonyms(value="entity 2", synonyms=["synonym 3", "synonym 4"])
entity_2 = Entity(id="entity_id_2", name=entity_synonyms_2)                

replace_entity_directive = DynamicEntitiesDirective(update_behavior=UpdateBehavior.REPLACE, types=[EntityListItem(name="custom_type", values=[entity_1, entity_2])])

response_builder.add_directive(replace_entity_directive)
```